# Relation modeling vs normalization

Tags: data-modeling, data-management

I have homework from my teacher and he say that which one is better (relation modeling or normalization) to make model of data in a hospital ? and why?

Comment: The question from your teacher makes no sense. Relational and normalisation are not options within the same set of choices but independent options - so being asked to choose between them is irrational. It’s like being asked if a car should be red or automatic - instead of being asked if it should be red or black, or manual or automatic

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by relation modelling you mean dimensional modelling (usually associated with Kimball).

Normalisation is associated with 3NF form or Inmon style.

You have to ask yourself what is the data model for?  You cant design anything unless you know the purpose of it or the requirements for the 'product' you build/design.

If you use the model as a backend database for the hospital administration application, then use Normalised data model.
If you want to use the model for analytics then you use the Kimball or denormalised model.